# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project app submission error

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I submit a test Windows Phone Silverlight Project 8.1 and get this error when submit

```
The package identity associated with this update doesn't match the uploaded appx: "2e740376-677c-4df8-b1af-95b72863f017"
```

Windows Phone 8.0 project dont meet that error. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, but the solution is simple - the Package identity name and Windows Publisher Name in Windows Store Dashboard must match with the values inside the uploaded xap package.

You can find these values in the **Windows Store Dasboard** in the **App identity** section:

[image: Windows Phone Dashboard]

You then need to copy and paste these values inside your **Package.appxmanifest** file. Note you have to open this file using **text editor**. These values are not editable using the UI editor:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed it by going to my dashboard, looking inside my in-progress app, clicking details and there I could see my package id. I copied that and pasted it inside my package manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly as the error states, your package identity doesn't match. The GUID in your `WMAppManifest.xml` and `Package.appxmanifest` have to be identical (and would be so, had you done a new project, or upgraded an existing project). The Package Identity name also have to match with the values from the Store submission process.

And if you're submitting to an existing application ID on the store, you obviously have to use the same GUID as you previously used for submitted.